# Limpar apenas uma linha de um arquivo batch

Tags: cmd, batch

Minha dúvida é se há alguma forma de apagar apenas uma linha de várias. 
**Por exemplo**: o comando imprime três números na tela do *prompt*:

```
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
```

E então, ele apaga apenas o "2" impresso, e os outros dois números continuarem ali.

Tem como?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente apagar não tem como.

O que pode ser feito é dar o comando `cls` e reimprimir na tela sem a segunda linha.

Exemplo:

```
@echo off

echo 1
echo 2
echo 3

pause
rem Apaga tudo que foi impresso.
cls

echo 1
echo 3

pause > nul
```

Comment: sim, eu imaginei a mesma coisa, obrigado mesmo assim